# My website with title is not appearing in google search

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, wordpress, yoast

When I search my company name "XYZ" in google, it is not appearing. I have submitted sitemap to google search console and have done SEO Yoast optimization. What am I missing ?

Comment: How long ago?  It isn't instant...

Comment: Oh, Its new website, like just been three weeks.How long will it take?  I am new to SEO. thanks

Comment: It takes anything between 4 days to 4 week. Can you share the website URL?

Comment: https://letmecare.com.au

When I type Let me care.. other website comes up ...

Comment: https://letmecare.com.au

Comment: Have you tried searching for "let me care disability service"?  Your site is right there.  "let me care" is a pretty generic term.  People fight for the front page.